# Document AI : Using FUNSD dataset to train a GNN to classify 'Linked' entities

Tags: classification, python, data-transformation, natural-language, graph-theory

I have been using the [FUNSD](https://guillaumejaume.github.io/FUNSD/) dataset to predict sequence labeling in unstructured documents per this paper: [LayoutLM: Pre-training of Text and Layout for Document Image Understanding](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.13318) . The data after cleaning and moving from a dict to a dataframe, looks like this:
[image: FUNSD Dataframe] The dataset is laid out as follows:

- The column `id` is the unique identifier for each **word group**
  inside a document, shown in column `text`  (like Nodes)
- The column`label` identifies whether the **word group** are classified as a
  'question' or an 'answer'
- The column `linking` denoting the **WordGroups** which are 'linked' (like Edges), linking corresponding 'questions' to 'answers'
- The column `'box'` denoting the location
  coordinates (x,y top left, x,ybottom right) of the **word group**
  relative to the top left corner (0.0).
- The Column `'words'` holds each ***individual word*** inside the **wordgroup**, and its location (box).

I aim to train a classifier to identify words inside the column `'words'` that are linked together by using a Graph Neural Net, and the first step is to be able to transform my current dataset into a Network. My questions are as follows:

1. I can break each row in the column `'words'` into a two columns `[box_word, text_word]`, each
   only for one word, while replicating the other columns which remain
   the same: `[id, label, text, box]`, resulting in a final dataframe with these columns: `[box,text,label,box_word, text_word]`
2. I can Tokenize the columns `'text'` and `text_word`, one hot encode column `label`, split columns with more than one numeric `box` and `box_word` into individual columns , but How do I split up/rearrange the colum `'linking'` to define the edges of my Network Graph?
3. Am I taking the correct route in Using the dataframe to generate a Network, and use it to train a GNN?

Any and all help/tips is appreciated.